# Oil all over outside of engine

Tags: motorcycle, oil-leak, yamaha, small-engine

[image]I have a 1988 yamaha route 66....I put some oil in, it has a slow leak by kickstand...I took it for a 5 mile ride last night. Afterwards I found it  sitting in oil, and the outter engine /side was covered in oil on the side opposite kickstand- so not from the old leak.

Any ideas? Did I blow the engine ?  Thanks

Ok, here is the edited version:  the oil runs out quickly from it seems- the air filter -when running (the silver roundish part directly below and left of the words "route 66")  the bottom of the air filter case was covered and dripping oil

Answer (score 2):

If the engine will run, I doubt you've "blown the engine". Usually a blown engine indicates that it's dead. Caputski. Bon Voyage. Sailed for greener pastures.

In your case, I would bet one of the gaskets has let go of the goods. It appears that the side case of your engine has three parts to it. I think there are some easy things to check:

[image]

- Check to ensure the oil fill is securely fastened (red arrow). May just be that simple.
- One of the three gaskets may be bad (green arcs - follow the seams all the way around the cover, not just where the arcs are at). You may be able to alleviate any leaks in these areas by simply tightening the fasteners. If not, you'd need to get new gaskets to seal this back up.
- Any of the fasteners in the covers may be loose, causing oil to leak past it.

First thing you need to do is to figure out where the oil is actually coming from. Until you do that, it's all a crap shoot. Clean the engine up and then check it for leaks. If you have fresh oil in it, this may be a little difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: I strongly feel that it might be the oil seal from the clutch plate compartment is blown.(middle arrow) ,

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your responses......I did put more oil in, started it up, and the oil is running out of what I thought was the air filter on the side where the oil case is....so higher up then the case, that round silver part, which is an air filter on one side---and looks the same on the other....It seems to be pouring out of there when the bike starts running. Any ideas about that ? Thanks again!

Comment: @Rose - Can you provide a picture of exactly what you are talking about? Put some annotations on it where it's leaking? Edit your original post with the info :D

Comment: yes, thank you Paul....I have done that above as you've requested....I think there is a connection between the fact that I had just added oil, thinking it may be low but unable to tell- maybe I put too much in ?

Comment: That is a very nice picture of your motorcycle. Can you please show us where it is leaking from? Maybe a closeup of the area?

Comment: from the description it looks like its leaking at the top of the cylinder head behind the air filter...

Comment: My friend is telling me the head is on top of those v's and the crank is in there. Maybe a crank seal